# Change pathway on Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I was just given the task of taking over some old queries from another colleague that left the department a few months ago. Some of the reports are linked to his personal documents. Can I change the path from the requested document into my files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you'll have to find out the actual link to the Excel files. They'll be in the **Table** section of

In your example, the query is **FROM ASRSVelocity**, which is a different query in your project. You'll have to check that query and see if it relates to a link - it may be another query.

The links are in the **Tables** section of Access and have a special icon like the one in the pic (**Results**). Click on them to open to see if you get an error. If you do, it will tell you the name of the file. Rename the link (so you have the old one to reference) and create a new link with the old name that's linked to the new file.

[image]